# Audio card not detected by Alsa (but Kernel does)

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

On Ubuntu 16.04, I'm trying to play sounds from this card (integrated 3.5mm analog output):

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
```

However, it appears ALSA is not able to detect it.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This is what `alsamixer` shows for this card:
[no audio controls for PCH audio card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdkut.png)

However, from the followings, it appears the kernel is able to detect the card and the `snd_hda_intel` driver is assigned to it:

```
    $ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
    00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 128, IRQ 133
    Memory at c1140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at c1130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Also

```
    $ cat /proc/asound/cards
    0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
    HDA Intel PCH at 0xc1140000 irq 133
```

I have two more identical machines with the same exact Kernel version and versions of `alsa-base` and `alsa-tools`. ALSA can correctly detect the PCH audio card on those. Any idea on how to solve ALSA interface with this card?

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374078/primary-sound-card-not-detected-by-alsamixer) but the answer doesn't seem to really answering the question (at least not the way I understand it). Also found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196472), but solution was not working for me.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm